# Android как создать карусель такого рода?

Tags: android

Мне нужно что-то примерно такое как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу использовать Rotate анимацию, а так же почему то не нашел библиотек на гитхабе которые могли бы помочь, прошу наставить меня на путь истинный)

Comment: Translate question to russian, plz, as you are on russian brach od SO

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перевел, поможете?

Answer (score 1):

На чистом Android вам конечно удастся такое сделать, но сложно. Я бы смотрел на 2d игровые движки - например libGDX. Там будет что-то такое:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-textureregions,-and-sprite
Sprite

The Sprite class describes both a texture region, the geometry where it will be drawn, and the color it will be drawn.

```
private Sprite sprite;
...
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
sprite = new Sprite(texture, 20, 20, 50, 50);
sprite.setPosition(10, 10);
sprite.setRotation(45);
...
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

Comment: А вы не знаете, возможно, есть библиотеки с похожим функционалом рандомной выдачи предметов из масива